# Properties of Connected Closed Trails?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, eulerian-path

Consider the (sub)graph below. I am allowing for the possibility of additional edges and nodes, and just want to look at the features of this subgraph.

What seems apparent is that there is not a trail that will hit every edge (some edge would have to be repeated). However, this was constructed by overlapping a few closed trails or connecting them via some path.

I am wondering what concepts are available to describe something like this, if any? Specifically, by 'this' I mean a subgraph that is constructed by connecting several closed trails, either by allowing them to share some edges (the two cycles on the left), or by drawing a path between them (for example, there is a vertical path between the figure 8 closed trail and the cycle NOPN).

[image]

Comment: I don't understand: However, this was constructed by overlapping a few closed trails.

Comment: @Salomo by overlapping, I mean allowing those trails (or cycles) to share an edge or multiple edges (the two cycles on the left).

Comment: Then it is just connectedness, nothing special, because a path is a closed trail allowing edges reused.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks.